# Has anyone other than GM Axel Smith and GM Hans Tikkanen had success improving their chess through the "Woodpecker Method"?

Tags: training

The Woodpecker Method was introduced in the book *Pump Up Your Rating* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=avlCnwEACAAJ)) by GM Axel Smith ([FIDE](http://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=1707930)), who was inspired by a training method used by GM Hans Tikkanen ([FIDE](http://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=1706446)), who used it to improve his chess.  A subsequent book *The Woodpecker Method* ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=HfUQvgEACAAJ)) was published by the two GMs.

A description of this method is given in [Brian Towers's answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19568/2785), but it involves repeatedly solving tactics problems (not only *what's the best move?* But, also, *what are the critical lines?*).

There's some debate online (see e.g. [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/chesscom-tactics-trainer---the-woodpecker-method)) as to whether this helped Axel Smith improve, or if this was attributable to other aspects of his chess training.  Hence my question:

**Question**: Has anyone other than GM Axel Smith and GM Hans Tikkanen had success improving their chess through the "Woodpecker Method"?

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer along the lines of "John Smith used this method for training starting 2013, and his rating improved from 1200 to 1900 in 8 months."  Or some other evidence that this method works in practice.  [I gave a simple description of the Woodpecker method, and a link to a more detailed description.]

Answer (score 4):

In the chapter *Woodpecker History* from the book *The Woodpecker Method*, Hans Tikkanen says this:

> I was obviously asked by many people about what I had done to finally
>   take the step from IM to GM. I described the method and my rationale
>   for adopting it, and several others decided to give it a go. One
>   Swedish trainer has apparently invited his students in the north of
>   our country to work dedicatedly on the method for a while.

But, tantalisingly, he does not name names.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe as the Woodpecker method is a standard training regime many players do. Solving tactics over and over is one of the best ways to improve. Explicitly identifying all the critical lines can only help.